# Display menu according to role sonataAdminBundle

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

How can I display the sidebare menus according to role under sonataAdminBundle?

That's what I did at:

config.yml

```
sonata.admin.group.livreur:
label: Livreur
label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle
icon: ''
items:
- cadicom.admin.livreur
```

security.yml

```
ROLE_ADMIN_LIVREUR:
- ROLE_ADMIN
- ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
- ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
- ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_MEDIA_ADMIN
- ROLE_APP_ADMIN_PROMOTIIN_ADMIN
- ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_HAS_MEDIA_ADMIN
- ROLE_CADICOM_ADMIN_LIVREUR_ADMIN
```

services.yml

```
cadicom.admin.livreur:
class: cadicomBundle\Admin\LivreurAdmin
arguments: [~, cadicomBundle\Entity\Livreur, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
tags:
- { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Livreur }
```

My pb is that the delivery section does not appear for the admin that's assigned the role ROLE_ADMIN_LIVREUR